# Odd behavior with OpenMP

Tags: c++, debugging, openmp

I am typing in a Conjugate Residual solver for a problem I have. After testing everything worked in serial, I added some OpenMP directives to speedup my code, but something was not right.

The nodal values (members of `node`) were different from what I was getting with the serial implementation. I double checked that there were no duplicate entries in `activeNodes`, and I cannot think of any race condition that is happening here.

Below is the problematic code block.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(THREAD_COUNT) reduction(+:residualSum) 

for(int i=0;i<activeNodes.size();i++){

    auto dataIt = activeNodes.begin();
    std::advance(dataIt,i);
    GridNode* node = dataIt->second;        

    node->r     =  -(node->consts.beta * node->consts.dt2 / (node->mass + EPS_D)) * node->getHessianSum(node->velNext);
    node->s     =  node->r + (node->consts.beta * node->consts.dt2 / (node->mass + EPS_D)) * node->getHessianSum(node->r);
    node->p     =  node->r;
    node->q     =  node->s;
    node->gamma =  dot(node->r,node->s);        
    node->alpha   = node->gamma / (dot(node->q,node->q) + EPS_D);


    residuals[i] = node->alpha * node->alpha * node->p.norm2();
    residualSum += residuals[i];

    std::cout << "what node->r should be : " << -(node->consts.beta * node->consts.dt2 / (node->mass + EPS_D)) * node->getHessianSum(node->velNext) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "node->r after assignment : " << node->r << std::endl;

}
```

Note : `node->getHessianSum()` does not modify any values.

Most of the time (99%), `what node->r should be` equals `node->r after assignment` exactly. On some occasions, they are completely different, like here :

```
    what node->r should be : (9.59679e-18,-7.9126e-18,-5.45652e-17)
    node->r after assignment : (1.1954e-05,6.24484e-06,-2.01226e-06)
```

The nodes that gets screwed up differs with respect to each run, and `node->r after assignment` is always different.

These errors destroys all the other calculations. I have been looking into this all day, and I am at my wits end. Any suggestions on what is wrong with my code?

Comment: If your code runs in parallel then writing to std::cout will produce random results.

Comment: Apart from the output ordering with threads, I don't see any immediate issues. It may very well hide in the things that you don't show. Very important would be the types of `activeNodes` and `residuals`. Try to break it down to a [mcve] so that we can *really* help - maybe you find the issue yourself on the way there.

Comment: You are writing into shared memory through an iterator on the `activeNodes` object.  It is impossible to tell whether you race.